# What is Bitcoin's locktime feature exactly? How can it be used?

Tags: locktime

What is Bitcoin's locktime feature and what are some example use cases?

And how can a user make use of this new feature? Is it in any gui wallet? And how would one use it in the command line if its the only option?

Comment: Does https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/23792/5406 answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like a cheque with a date in future, a Bitcoin transaction with locktime cannot be unlocked (read cashed) before that date. The definition in bitcoin.org is pretty clear

> Part of a transaction which indicates the earliest time or earliest
>   block when that transaction may be added to the block chain.

Sample use case is a cautionary deposit. For a great example see micropayment channel protocol implemented by bitcoinj and described here:

https://bitcoinj.github.io/working-with-micropayments

Comment: You lost me there with all the A B Q Tx Tx2 variables.

Comment: well, reedited with Alice and Bob. Not easy to explain without the proper actors

Comment: what is coin Q?

Comment: a coin is a sum linked to the output of a past transaction and that can be spent becoming the input of another.